# Return single value thymeleaf

Tags: java, jsp, thymeleaf

Hello I have code like this:

```
<div style="display: inline;"><a id="select-sector" class="selectpicker"  data-live-search="true" th:for="${sifr == sector}">
    <option th:each="s : ${sectors}"  th:text="${s.desc}" ></option>
</a></div>

<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" ><big>Title <a th:if="${dateFro != null}" style="color: black;">for <a th:text="${dateBy}" style="color: black;"></a></a> to <a th:text="${dateBy}" style="color: black;"></a>
<a th:if="${sector != null}" style="color: black;">Sub text
<div style="display: inline;"><a id="select-sector" class="selectpicker"  data-live-search="true" >
    <option th:each="s : ${sectors}" th:for="${s.sifr== sector}"  th:text="${s.desc}" ></option>
</a></div></a>                   
<a th:if="${lev != null}" style="color: black;">, Levels <a th:text="${lev}" style="color: black;"></a></a>
</big>.
</h5>
```

I'm trying to return single sector value, right now it returns me all sectors, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option tags should have `value` attribute, not `for`. That is meant for label tags. Change that line with:

```
<option th:each="s : ${sectors}" 
        th:value="${s.sifr}" 
        th:selected="${s.sifr == sector}"
        th:text="${s.desc}">
</option>
```